# Safe Background size

Tags: android

So I want to use a png as the background for my android application.

[image: Sample Background]

The condition is that the biggest snowflake:

[image: Big Snowflake]

is always at the top right corner. I can scale the image proportionately only, because otherwise, the snowflake will end up looking like a bunch of I don't know whats:

[image: Thorns]

Given the plethora of device resolution and dpi's available, what is a reasonable way to achieve what I want?

**Update:**
I am aware of 9-patch. But my background cannot be expressed in terms of a 9-patch. At best, what I can do is include the source in the largest dimensions (proportionately) possible. In my case, the source is 1920X2400 in size. To rephrase my question, what would be the safest size (with uniform scaling) to include in my app?

Here's an example:

[image: Non-9Patch drawable]

> Image copyright of original authors. Used here, only for illustration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this: 
Use `RelativeLayout` to set the image at top right corner of its parent container, and resize the image proportionally according to the screen size

example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
     <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:src="@drawable/expander_close_holo_dark" /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

As long as you provide the image via `android:src` android automatically resizes it preserving the ratio.

Answer (score 1):

Use a 9-patch. See [HERE](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch). And [HERE](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) is how to make one. They scale only the portions of the image that you define as scaleable & leave the rest.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I did not mention this. I am aware of 9 patch, but my graphic cannot be expressed in terms of 9 patch. My illustrative example was perhaps, insufficient. See edit.

Comment: Ah, so you want to hack off differing amounts from the height so that none of the image is scaled at all?

Comment: No, I can scale as long as it is uniform and maintains the original aspect ratio. Problem is, a typical "phone" would have a 3:4 ratio of display dimensions, while a typical "tablet" may have a 4:3. So, what's my best bet given these constraints?

Comment: ..Have you read the [developer.android guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)?
You can choose different drawables for different screens & android will choose for you.